# Mantaining focus with lots of small interruptions

Tags: productivity, distractions

During my work there are a lot of small pauses, mostly due to outdated/clunky tools and PCs.
These pauses range from 10s to 1 min long, and it's really hard to keep focused on my work while being interrupted 5/6 times in a row.

I already brought this up with management and tried to automate all longer processes, but I'm now at a point where the only solution is buying better tools or hardware.
For example, I just had to copy a file from a network folder, and since we don't have gigabit ethernet it took about 90 seconds.

Management already denied buying other tools, as we are a medium-big company, and updating tools would require a major effort.

My productivity is high enough and this is not a huge problem, however I feel I could be a lot more productive in a proper environment.

How can I deal with a large amount of medium-small interruptions?

At the moment I'm already switching to other small tasks, but I take a lot of time to refocus again on what I was doing, and this is less than ideal.

Comment: @gnat that's not the question, though. "How can I deal with a large amount of medium-small interruptions?" is, although I suspect there's a duplicate for that out there too.

Comment: @stanri I already searched for similar questions, but they all dealt with being interrupted by colleagues/other sources. Anyway as you said, my question is not about convincing management to buy new tools, but about better coping with the ones already in place.

Comment: Make a list: Small interruption(~10s), Medium interruption (10-30s), long interruption (30s-60s), very long interruption (>60s). Every time you are interrupted, update your list. When you have ample evidence, go to management. make it clear that a 10s interruptionccosts 20s 8at least) of working time because you need to re-focus. if you can show them that you waste 20mins per hour waiting, thats 30%. If new hardware/software cuts that down to 5 minutes, its only 8%. Its not only happening to you, but to others as well. That way you have *quantitative* arguments for new software.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear, I don't feel it's duplicate to any of the questions linked, as one deals with convincing management to buy new tools, and the other has answers mostly focusing on the "compiling" factor

Comment: Having to wait is **not** an interruption. It's idle time. *You* doing other small tasks in that time **is** an interruption. Just make sure you get your terms clear.